# OnClickListener not getting Invoked for ToogleButton

Tags: android

I'm try to listen a ToogleButton and written toogleButton.setOnClickListener inside onCreate method as below but the method is not getting invoked when i click the tooglebutton

Please let me know what is going wrong..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the EditText and Toggle buttons

        final ToggleButton toggleBttn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tggle);

        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        // listen to toggleButton click

        toggleBttn.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(toggleBttn.isChecked())
                {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    System.out.println(" Its On");
                }
                else
                {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
                    System.out.println(" Its Off ");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Also below is Activity XML

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter Password" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ToggleButton 
        android:id="@+id/tggle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        />
```

UPDATED CODE

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the EditText and Toggle buttons

        final ToggleButton toggleBttn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tggle);

         final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        // listen to toggleButton click

        toggleBttn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(isChecked)
                {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                System.out.println(" Its On");
                }

                else
                {
                    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
                    System.out.println(" Its Off ");
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you try to remove the final identifier? May put static instead.

Comment: putting static is giving error

Comment: What?? why static?? Please don't mess up with OOPs concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong listener here, use `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Like this example...

```
ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        // The toggle is enabled
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled
    }
}
});
```

You can fine more info at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

I am doing this and its working.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.type);
    ToggleButton t = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tggle);
    t.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "is checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                e.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "is un-checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have changed to setOnCheckedChangeListener still its not getting called

Comment: I don't understand. I just tried it and it working. Are you getting the System.out.println output? Are you using `new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()`?? Use this. You might be using some other class

Comment: yeh..even i felt weird..SOP's are not getting printed in console..let me restart Simulator and try it

Comment: If output is getting printed correctly then its working. What else are you trying to do? This was your problem, right?

Comment: Are you using `new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()`?? Use this. You might be using some other class

Comment: I'm using the same CompoundButton..(android.widget.CompoundButton)